# Kivy MDtoolbar messing up other widgets (there positing)

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

I was trying to make a recording app while doing so I came across this error where my kivy widgets are not positioning properly and I believe the problem is the kivymd's MDToolbar but I don't wanna get rid of it. Can someone help me?

```
# simplified code
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
KV = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDToolbar:
        title: "MDToolbar"
    
    Widget:

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "record-circle"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        user_font_size: "64sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y": 1}
        
    MDIconButton:
        icon: "motion-play-outline"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        user_font_size: "32sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y": 1}

    MDIconButton:
        icon: "content-save"
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        user_font_size: "32sp"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.45, "y": 1}
"""


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

here is how it looking
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cbcmd.png)
the x-axis is working kids but the y-axis is not
HElp....

Comment: Do you need the widgets to be vertical and aligned to the center?

Comment: well yeah kinda but most horizontally I mean I kind of go up and down I'm okay will the x-axis

Answer (score 0):

Use FloatLayout:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
KV = """
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDToolbar:
        title: "MDToolbar"

    FloatLayout:
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "record-circle"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            #user_font_size: "64sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "center_y": .5}
            
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "pencil"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            #user_font_size: "32sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "center_y": .7}

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "content-save"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            #user_font_size: "32sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.8, "y": .8}
            
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "home"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            #user_font_size: "64sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.3, "center_y": .5}
            
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "menu"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            #user_font_size: "32sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.3, "center_y": .7}

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "dots-vertical"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            #user_font_size: "32sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.3, "y": .8}
            
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "home"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            #user_font_size: "64sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": .2}
            
        MDIconButton:
            icon: "menu"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            #user_font_size: "32sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.6, "center_y": .2}

        MDIconButton:
            icon: "dots-vertical"
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            #user_font_size: "32sp"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.7, "y": .2}
"""


class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)


Test().run()
```

Pictures:

[image]